# Finding optimal weights in regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am new to linear regression and sklearn.
I have a problem where I have input feature **x1**, which contains 101 ones and input feature   **x2** 100 ones and then a zero. The output y is all 101 ones.
I am trying to find the optimal value of w1 and w2.

I tried writing the below code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np
x = np.ones(202, dtype='int').reshape(101,2)
x[100,1]= 0
y = np.ones(101, dtype='int')
model = LinearRegression().fit(x,y)

print(f"w1 and w2: {model.coef_}")
```

The output I am getting is :`w1 and w2: [0. 0.]`, which I am sure is wrong.
It would be great if someone can help me in correcting the code.

**Edit**
The value of input x looks like below:

```
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 0]])
```

Comment: I'm away from my computer now and this isn't actually answering your question, but I think you meant `x[:,1]= 0`, right? Such that for every entry in your x, the values are `[1, 0]` ? Also, to make debugging easier, reduce the number of rows. Maybe 3 or 4 rows would help elucidate

Comment: Thank you @IanQ for the response. I edited the question to show the x values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LinearRegression model includes an intercept term by default, which you have omitted to monitor. The intercept, also known as the bias term, is denoted by `b` in the following equation solved by the linear regression:

```
y = w1 * x1 + w2 * x2 + b
```

Here, `w1` and `w2` are the model coefficients stored into the `model.coef_`, while the intercept is represented by `model.intercept_`.

To illustrate this, if you run your code and print the value of the intercept, you will notice that it takes a value of 1 when the model coefficients are zero:

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np

# Data
x = np.ones(202, dtype='int').reshape(101,2)
x[100,1]= 0
y = np.ones(101, dtype='int')

# Fit
model = LinearRegression().fit(x,y)

print(f"The coefficients are: {model.coef_}")
print(f"The intercept is: {model.intercept_}")
```

This will output:

```yaml
The coefficients are: [0. 0.]
The intercept is: 1.0
```

If you set fit_intercept to False, you will see that the model coefficients take on the expected values:

```py
model = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False).fit(x,y)

print(f"The coefficients are: {model.coef_}")
print(f"The intercept is: {model.intercept_}")
```

Output:

```yaml
The coefficients are: [1.00000000e+00 6.38320294e-17]
The intercept is: 0.0
```